# Prove by mathematical induction, or otherwise, that for all integers $n\ge 1$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

$$\cos(1)+\cos(2)+\ldots+\cos(n-1)= \cos(n)-\cos(n-1)/(2\cos(1)-2 ) -1/2$$

Here is my attempt:

Let $P(n)$ be this statement.

$P(1)$ is true since $0=\cos(1)-\cos(1-1)/(2\cos(1)-2)   -1/2$

Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some integer $k$. Then I have to prove $P(k+1)$ is also true. That is :

$$\cos(1)+\cos(2)+\ldots+\cos(k-1)+\cos(k)=\cos(k+1)-\cos(k)/(2\cos(1)-2) -1/2.$$

By inductive hypothesis, we have $\cos(k)-\cos(k-1)/(2\cos(1)-2 )  -1/2 +\cos(k)$. But how does it equal to the right hand side? Can someone help me with this question please, thank you!

Comment: Uh? How is $P(1)$ true? It looks false to me...

Comment: My tutor said P(1) was true, the left hand side is 0 which equals to the right hand side. I thought it was false as well..

Comment: It it false. The $1/2$ must be $1$

Answer (score 1):

By De Moivre, $e^{ik}=\cos k+i\sin k$. Then

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos k&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}Re(e^{ik})\\
&=&Re\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{ik}\right)\\
&=&Re\left(\frac{e^{in}-1}{e^i-1}-1\right)\\
&=&Re\left(\frac{\cos n+i\sin n}{\cos1+i\sin1-1}\right)-1\\
&=&Re\left(\frac{\cos n+i\sin n}{\cos1+i\sin1-1}\cdot\frac{\cos1-i\sin1-1}{\cos1-i\sin1-1}\right)-1\\
&=&Re\left(\frac{\cos n\cos1-i\cos n\sin 1-\cos n+i\sin n\cos1+\sin n\sin 1-i\sin n}{2-2\cos1}\right)-1\\
&=&\frac{\cos n\cos 1-\cos n+\sin n\sin 1}{2-2\cos 1}-1\\
&=&\frac{\cos(n-1)-\cos n}{2-2\cos1}-1
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Thanks, but how do you prove for P(k+1)?